# I have an Object of Array type contains some data. I want to set it to textview with comma seperation

Tags: android, textview

I'm getting response from API. I want to set Array objects to textView with comma seperation or like chips. How can i achieve this? Below is my code

```
String batch="";
  for (int i=0 ; i < batchModel.getTrainingMode().size() ; i++){
      batch = batchModel.getTrainingMode().get(i).getName();
  }
 tvTrainingModeType.setText(batch);
```

API response

```
            "TrainingMode": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Name": "Online"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Name": "Class Room"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 3,
                    "Name": "Certification"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 4,
                    "Name": "Training&Placement"
                },
                {
                    "Id": 5,
                    "Name": "Industrial Training"
                }
            ],
```

Comment: you can get all array data in one string variable then , at the end display this variable to the textview

Comment: From the above response i want to set all the Names to textview based on their id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate values to one text view, use this.

```
String result = "";
for(String name : coursesModel.getTrainingMode()){
result += ", " + name;
}

tvTrainingModeType.setText(result)
```

If you want chip view in android, refer [this](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f).

Comment: I need basedon ID